# How do I move the user's Temp Folder

Tags: directory

How do I move (settings/syntax) the user's Temp Folder to a new location inside their Home Folder?

Comment: I don't know of any standard directory for temporary files inside user directories. There's `$XDG_CACHE_HOME` (defaults to `~/.cache`) and `$XDG_RUNTIME_DIR` (which has no default), neither of which really fit the definition of "temporary files". What exactly do you mean?

Answer (score 1):

To do this, you need to set the $TMP environment variable. This can be done per-user or globally. More information is available [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EnvironmentVariables). What you need to do is add

```
TMP=${HOME}/tmp
```

to the appropriate file (e.g. ~/.pam_environment to set it for one user) where tmp is the dir inside the user(s)' home directory you want to use for temp files.

Changes take effect the next time the user logs in.